# Openshift Origin Offline/Disconnected Installation

Tags: openshift-origin

I want to install openshift origin containerized installation(advanced installation) on machine without internet access.
I referred to this URL -> https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/install_config/install/disconnected_install.html
But it still going to docker.io and registry.*.redhat.com.

Please suggest a possible approach to achieve the goal.

Comment: you most likely have to download the required images first from an internet connected machines and export them to the disconnected machine using docker save/load for example.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to accomplish this install.The updated documentation does list the steps.
Let me know if you are still looking for the steps.

Comment: Ccould you point at where the steps are listed within the documentation?